# Anchor tag height not fitting in TD

Tags: css, asp.net, html-table, treeview, anchor

I'm using tree view to populate rows in my webpage.
In html this is rendered as tables and anchor tags. The top edge and bottom edges are not being selected on hover (i.e. if we place mouse on the top edge of a item the anchor tag has no hover.

**problem**-
when I hover on Image, then anchor tag is not selected.

**problem**- I need edges to be covered by `<a>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/krishnathota/tGWsH/

1. I need edges to be covered by `<a>`.
2. I need color of the `<a>` anchor tag text to be changed when the mouse is hovered on the image.

Actually I have copied the pageSource from browser into the fiddle.
If you wish I wil give the treeview code.

Can you help me in achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tGWsH/2/)

You need to add another class by extending CSS.

So I have something to show you how-

**Added on anchor-**

```
.anchor-back
{
    background:#98bf26;
    color:white;
}
```

**Javascript-**

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $('a').removeClass('anchor-back');
    $(this).addClass('anchor-back');

});
```

I hope you will get an idea from here.

Comment: you didn't solve the problem actually. you just showed up to what extent the `<a>` is accessable

Answer (score 1):

Used to this

```
.treeView table tbody tr:hover a{

    color:#fff;

}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tGWsH/1/)

Comment: This works good for me. But can you make the top edge covered by the link ?? I need when we hover on the category the backgroundcolor changes when the mouse is on the very edge, then the hover color is intact but the link is unavailable there

Comment: If you see Manoz's Demo, In that we can see up to what extent the `<a>` tag is accessable. I need the `<a>` tag to be accessable every where in the Row. top 2 pixcel, and bottom 4 pixcels are left by `<a>`. can you solve that?